# Criar uma Label ou Input na vertical

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Preciso criar uma LABEL ou Input para que o texto digitado fique na Vertical, da seguinte maneira:

```
M
E
U 

T
E
X
T
O
```

Isso Seria possível de Alguma Maneira? Isso é necessário para a impressão de banners neste formato.

Comment: O texto ficará sempre nesse formato com uma letra por linha? Ou dependerá de alguma largura?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo de como colocar o texto vertical em outro elemento:

```js
var ele_input = document.getElementById('vert');
var ele_text = document.getElementById('put-text');
ele_input.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    // vamos tranformar o conteudo (texto) num array com todos os caracteres, colocar um <br> entre cada caracter e voltar a transformar em texto
    ele_text.innerHTML = ele_input.value.split('').join('<br>');
})
```

```html
<input id="vert">
<div id="put-text"></div>
```

[EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/sngcb5f6/) no jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Atualmente com CSS vc consegue o mesmo resultado, e até com um bom suporte dos browsers como vc pode consultar aqui: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-orientation (não funciona no IE ou Edge)

Com a propriedade `text-orientation: upright` vc define se o texto começa verticalmente de `lr` *left* para *right* ou de `rl` *right* para *left*. Já com o `text-orientation` vc coloca os caracteres *"um sobre o outro"* verticalmente Aqui vc pode ler a documentação da Mozilla sobre o assunto: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation#Values

Veja como fica no exemplo:

```css
p {
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
      -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
          writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;

  height:135px;
  border:1px solid
}
```

```html
<p>texto na vertical</p>
```